# My Api returns a 201 status but the client application returns a 500 status, is there something i am missing?

Tags: c#, api, client

so both applications are running on https and on local host when i debug the api completes successfully and does return a 201 status and updates the database successfully.

```
[HttpPost()]
    [Route("api/dealers/add")]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> CreateDealer([FromBody] DealerForCreation dealerForCreation)
    {
        // get the environments web root path 
        var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

        var dealer = new Dealer { Name = dealerForCreation.Name };

        //create the filename
        var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        // the full filepath
        var filePath = Path.Combine($"{webRootPath}/images/dealers/{filename}");

        // write bytes and close stream
        await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, dealerForCreation.Bytes);

        //add the filename to the dealer 
        dealer.ImageFileName = filename;

        // add and save the dealer
        var newDealer = await _dealerService.CreateAsync(dealer).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var result = CreatedAtRoute("GetDealer", new { newDealer.Id });
        return result;

    }
```

However the client application doesn't seem to recieve the 201 and instead gets a 500. Is there something simple i have missed?

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("QuestHelper/Dealers/Add")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(CreateDealerViewModel createDealerViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Add", createDealerViewModel);
        }
        // create a dealerforcreation instance
        var dealerForCreation = new DealerForCreation { Name = createDealerViewModel.Name };
       
        //if the file exists read the stream and copy to memory.
        if (createDealerViewModel.File !=  null)
        {
            using var fileStream = createDealerViewModel.File.OpenReadStream();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                dealerForCreation.Bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        // serialize it
        var serializedDealerForCreation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dealerForCreation);
        // get the client and the request
        GetClientAndRequest(HttpMethod.Post, route: "/api/dealers/add");
        request.Content = new StringContent(serializedDealerForCreation,
            Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).
            ConfigureAwait(false);
        var status = response.StatusCode; // returns 500 error .. don't know why.. the api returns 201
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

I have tried running it synchronously and also without validating the anti-forgery token and still get the same result.

Comment: Often this happens on a local server and when app is installed in a server like IIS application will fail.  You are getting an internal error 500 in the server when the processing is being done in the server.  On a IIS the default credentials is GUEST which does not have access to the server resources like the file system.  See ROLES : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: but the files are still being created? I'm pretty new to coding and self taught, this is the first api I have attempted the local server is just IIS Express if that is any help

Comment: The error is in the server.  You are running on a IIS with difference credentials (than running locally) and causing an exception. You can check the Event Viewer on the Server to see if there are any error that will help solve issue.

Comment: so instead of using createdAtRoute i have just returned a straight 201 status with no object, that works fine so It's more a routing issue I would say, i've done a temporary fix foe now until i have more time.